# Saving data (user statistics) in a table form JAVA

Tags: java, user-data

I am coding a minesweeper game in Java and am using DefaultTableModel for a simple user statistics table.  I can add new users and update their stats (Games Played and Games Won). This is working fine for the simplicity of it. But I am finding each time I compile, I am losing the data I created in the last run. Is there a way to save the data permanently? Or is there a better system I can use to save the users and their stats permanently.

Answer (score 1):

In order to permanently store the data you will need to put it on some sort of storage device e.g HDD.  Some ways of doing this could be to store it in something simple like a text file and reading it back into the program as needed.  The advantage here being it is relatively simple to read/write to a txt file using Java.  This method however this does expose your information to the outside world unless you encrypt it,  and if you have vast amounts of data, may not be the best way.

An alternate is to use a Database, something like Apache Derby to store the information in, and then when you reload your program read the information back from it.  That way your information is stashed somewhere permanently and you can easily access/modify/save it programmatically.  This option however is a bit more complex as you need at the least a basic understanding of JDBC and SQL.

Good Luck!